# $y$ Pauli Operators Eigenvectors - How are they orthogonal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

I am struggling to obtain that the eigenvectors of the Pauli $y$ operator are orthogonal, and would appreciate guidance on where I am going wrong. I have calculated the eigenvalues as: 1, -1

And eigenvectors as:

$$
\binom{1}{i}
$$

And

$$
\binom{1}{-i}
$$

When I take the inner product of these, I get to 2. When normalised I get to 1. I understood that a way to verify if eigenvectors are orthogonal is to check the inner product equals 0, however I can't seem to get to this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find
$$
(1,i)^* \left(\begin{matrix} 1\cr -i\end{matrix}\right)= (1,-i) \left(\begin{matrix} 1\cr -i\end{matrix}\right)= 1-1=0.
$$

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much - did you take the conjugate transpose of the first vector?

Comment: Yes, the inner product has to complex conjugate the entries in the left-hand vector:  $\langle x|y\rangle= \sum_i x^*_i y_i $

Comment: Thank you for explaining!